# Angular change detection triggers after every handler?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, dom

Let say I have two click handlers attached to dom inside template:

```
<div (click)="handleClick()">
  <p (click)="handleClick()">
    Start editing to see some magic happen :)
  </p>
</div>
```

and following in ts file:

```
export class AppComponent implements DoCheck {
  handleClick(){
    console.log('AppComponent: handle click');
  }

  ngDoCheck(){
    console.log('AppComponent: ngDoCheck');
  }
}
```

Now, if someone clicks on **p** element, change detection is fired after every click handler (ngDoCheck executed twice). When I add more handlers, number of change detection phases increase accordingly.

Here's example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-czdzzk

In this trivial example it's harmless, but I'm currently working on a bigger application, where there are tens of components on the page, and multiple handlers attached (mainly to window.document by external libraries). In this case, after clicking anywhere on the page, components are checked many times.

Is there a way to execute change detection once after all handlers are executed? Or is it implemented this way for some reason?

Comment: Why are you calling the `handler` on the click callback of both `<div>` and `<p>` ? That is why the function is getting called twice. Please read on event-bubbling
https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: It is just for example. In reality these handlers are attached to window.document by different components.

Comment: On development mode, Angular runs one additional Change Detection cycle, for debugging purposes, but stackblitz runs in production, so in this case you simply facing an event bubbling - https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: The only way to prevent auto-check of change. Is you taking control of the triggering the changes manually by using `onPush` https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#use-markforcheck-with-checkonce-strategy
But in my experience, if you choose the right data-structures and shared services. This auto change detection is not, really a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.onPush` [Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy#OnPush). You should **always use onPush**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'selector'
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.onPush,
  //...
})
export default MyComponent {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Right, it shortens change detection phase, but it is still executed many times. Unfortunately, lots of our components are written in a way that makes them OnPush unfriendly :/

Comment: Those are bad components mate. You should really consider refactoring those.